# How does the buoyant force on an object change as its being lowered into water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Buoyancy
I for one cannot find any answer to my question and myself am quite confused.Google isn't very much help for the question I have.I researched "how does it change as it being submerged into water"still I had no answer after I had searched it.

Answer (score 1):

[Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) states that the magnitude of the buoyancy force is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced, so as more of the object is submerged, the buoyancy force increases.

Answer (score 1):

The buoyancy force is the weight of the fluid displaced by the object. Mathematically, $$B=\rho g V_\mathrm{submerged}$$
The buoyancy force depends only on the volume **submerged** in the water. If the object is fully submerged in water then the buoyancy force won't change until some part of the object is lifted out of the water.